# The email or password you entered is incorrect jQuery ?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a task:
I have a log in box with username and password. And if combination of the email and user is incorrect when click the button log in to display text message "The email or password you entered is incorrect." with only **jQuery**. What do you think is it possible to check something like this in html page with  jQuery . I think I need dynamic page and database and I need to use something like PHP ?
Thanks for the opinion!

Comment: jQuery can be use in html page, not necessary to have dynamic page like jsp, asp etc

Comment: I mean is it possible to do this check with jQuery, how I know username and password I think I need to have dynamic page with register form and save data somewhere and check combination ?

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980919/login-check-using-jquery-ajax-php

Comment: Not clear which bit you need help on? Have you tried something you have a problem with? Yes, it's possible... perhaps start with an online example somewhere and go from there?

Comment: with language for dynamic programming is possible yes, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need database for sure to validate that combination is wrong. for doing it you can simply use ajax call to send values to a PHP page which then validate it with database query and the return you tru or false based on that response you can show error message on your page.

You can take refrence rom here 
[How to validate a username / password via JQuery / Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059777/how-to-validate-a-username-password-via-jquery-ajax)

Comment: Give sample example make easy to understand solution and help other to understand without clicking on link provided.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got it the right way

Comment: providing sample needs to be very specific related to the question but I have provided link as it can be referred however if user wants something ready to eat that is not lways possible you have put some effort atleast. We are here to help not to feed anybody ready-made answer :)

Comment: @user2169710 if my answer has done what you need you can mark it accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

```
I think I need dynamic page and database and I need to use something like PHP ?
```

True if you want to validate the user's username and password server side. You would be able to partially use jQuery with an ajax request, but you would still need some response from the server (which you could use PHP for) and you would need some database for the server to query.

Another option is to use something like [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/), which is a client-side data management service. You would then be able to query and validate user credentials all client-side, but it would likely be insecure and not recommended.

Their Documentation: https://www.firebase.com/docs/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well you shouldn't ask for opinions here but anyway if your useres are saved in a, lets say mysql database, you need defenitly a server side language (php...). Javascript and jquery are client side languages. That would mean that you need to send every visitor a list of every user, to check for a correct login.

Comment: That is ,because they ask me to do only with jQuery I think is not possible. Thanks!

Comment: No, not in a secure way

Comment: Just in case it helped, you can accept it :)